# How to use events in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am newbie to socket.io,and I was looking for the events like `"message"`
and I want to know what are they aside from message.

```
socket.on('message', function (msg) {

});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create your own events; they are not predefined, ie:

```
socket.on('< whatever you want >', function (payload) {
   console.log('Hello World')
});

socket.emit('< whatever you want >', payload);

>>> 'Hello World'
```

For example:

```
socket.on('marco', function (payload) {
   console.log(payload.msg)
});

socket.emit('marco', {msg: 'polo!'});

>>> 'polo!'
```

There are some special names that are [restricted](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/b31ac185549f296839727aea4f4699c51200ee4a/lib/socket.js#L18-L30) however. These are:

- 'error'
- 'connect'
- 'disconnect'
- 'newListener'
- 'removeListener

Comment: Thank you for giving example

Comment: can you please show me the demo,I could not run the example